# Why does this list changes after using append() on another list

Tags: python, list

I don't know if I miss something here but don't understand why does the below list changes after using append() function. First I send a list(which contains lists) to 2 different functions.

First function just returns a random list in all non-empty lists. Second function returns a random list that if the current list(which is the one returned from the first function)'s last element lower than the other list in `state` or if the list is empty.

```
import random
def fooOne(state):
    lst = [x for x in state if len(x) > 0]
    return random.choice(lst)

def fooTwo(state,current):
    lst2 = [x for x in state if len(x) == 0 or x[-1] > current[-1]]
    return random.choice(lst2)

state = [[3, 2, 1],
         [],
         []]

cur = fooOne(state)
temp = fooTwo(state,cur)

print("State before append(): {}".format(state))
temp.append(cur.pop())
print("State after append(): {}".format(state))
```

Both functions returns different lists. I assign these lists to two different variables called `cur` and `temp`. So both `cur` and `temp` are also lists.

After `temp.append(cur.pop())` line, original `state` list changes. It'll changes like I used that line on the original list. But I'm making this operation on two different lists.

Output:

```
State before append(): [[3, 2, 1], [], []]
State after append(): [[3, 2], [], [1]]
```

Why does the original list changes while I'm using append() on another list? These lists are just some parts of the original list, why modifying them(while assigning them to new variables) affects the original list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)   PS: Loved your profile.

Comment: You didn't change a different list; you changed the same list under a second name.

Comment: @CeliusStingher No I already checked that question. I'm not modfying the original list, I assign them to another variables.

Comment: I can only see 1 list "state"

Comment: You return a shallow copy of the list, i.e. the most internal lists are not copied. Try: `lst2 = [list(x) for x in state if len(x) == 0 or x[-1] > current[-1]]` and see it working as expected?

Comment: Your functions pick sublists out of `state` without making any copies. When you perform `temp.append(cur.pop())` you are modifying one of those sublists which are still in `state`. Therefore printing `state` shows you what has changed.

Comment: Use the `id()` method to see whether you have a different list.  Just as in the duplicate, you made other references to `state`; giving those references other explicit names doesn't change the fact that it's still a reference to `state`.

Comment: The answer is that you aren't modifying two lists, you're modifying one list with two references. One variable can have two references; modifying one modifies them both.

Answer (score 0):

The original list 'state' changes because it is sharing data with 'temp' where you append to. To better understand the Python Data Model use:

https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/

to see your data as a graph.

```
import memory_graph # see install instructions at link above
import random
def fooOne(state):
    lst = [x for x in state if len(x) > 0]
    return random.choice(lst)

def fooTwo(state,current):
    lst2 = [x for x in state if len(x) == 0 or x[-1] > current[-1]]
    return random.choice(lst2)

state = [[3, 2, 1],
         [],
         []]
memory_graph.d() # draw graph

cur = fooOne(state)
memory_graph.d() # draw graph
temp = fooTwo(state,cur)
memory_graph.d() # draw graph

print("State before append(): {}".format(state))
temp.append(cur.pop())
memory_graph.d() # draw graph
print("State after append(): {}".format(state))
```

After "state = [[3, 2, 1], [], []]":

[image]

After "cur = fooOne(state)":

[image]

After "temp = fooTwo(state,cur)":

[image]

After "temp.append(cur.pop())":

[image]

Full disclosure: I am the developer of [memory_graph](https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/).